# adding two variables that represent integers

Tags: python-2.7

I have been making an AI (in python 2.7.11) which can be used as a personal entertainment tool/calculator/whatever else and seem to have encountered a problem. I can't add two variables that I got from the raw_input function.
instead of getting 19 in a test, I got 712. I'll give you some code in context to help:

```
mp=raw_input('do you want to add, subtract, multiply, divide, use exponents, or squareroot?:')

if mp=='add':

     numx=raw_input('what number for x in a problem x _ y?:')

     numy=raw_input('what number for y in a problem x _ y?:')

     print (numx+numy)
```

Comment: replace last sentence with `print (int(numx) + int(numy))`

Comment: you need to convert the input to int since you receive them as string in the first place...

Comment: raw_input returns a string so you have to explicitly convert it back to an integer `int(numx)` and `int(numy)` you could put that in a try block and handle the exception if you're not sure of the value you're getting from the user

Answer (score 2):

The result of `raw_input` is a *string* so, if you add together the strings `'7'` and `'12'`, you will indeed get `'712'`. This is string concatenation rather than numeric addition.

To get numeric addition, you need to turn them into numeric values before attempting to add them, and this can be done with something like:

```
try:
    intx = int(numx)
    inty = int(numy)
    print intx + inty
except ValueError:
    print 'One or both could not be converted'
```

The `int()` calls try to convert the string values into numeric values and then adds them together. The `try...except` code is simply to handle invalid input data.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line, cast strings to int.

```
print (int(numx)+int(numy))
```